# How should I advertise DNS of my pi server running pi-hole and pivpn using router as DHCP server?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi

I have installed pivpn and then pi-hole on my raspberry pi, and have decided to use DHCP from router.

so I updated my raspberry pi `/etc/hosts` file shown below.

```
192.168.1.187   192.168.1.1
127.0.1.1       titan
192.168.1.187   titan
```

for someone reason 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as DNS  on my phone even if I renew lease !
where are these setup